# continued condition checking on a loop of functions

Tags: python

I have a list of functions which take a long time to execute each.  I want to write a loop which executes all these functions but after each function it rechecks a flagging condition I have put in place to break out of the loop.  This is to save time if requires.

For example if I have functions from A to D,

```
while flag==0:
    A()
    B()
    C()
    D()
```

Can I write this in a way that after A is executed it rechecks to see if flag==0.  I am trying NOT to write it like,

```
if flag==0:
    A()
if flag==0:
    B()
if flag==0:
    C()
if flag==0:
    D()
```

I am doing this because I cannot get an interrupt function to work correctly to break out of executing code as soon as a button is pressed.

Thanks for any help

Comment: Do the functions need to be run repeatedly until the flag is true or just once each?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your functions have no arguments, you can make a list of functions since functions are first class objects:-

```
my_functions = [A, B, C, D]

for function in my_functions:
    while flag == 0:
        function()
```

In case functions need some arguments, then you need to specifically use lambda's

```
my_functions = [lambda : A(1, 2), lambda : B(3, 2) ...]

for function in my_functions:
    while flag == 0:
        function()
```

Comment: Using this method seems to be changing the values of some of the data from a list I'm putting into it (arguments).  Not sure why.

Comment: A mix of hspandher and joshromrock worked for me, for some reason putting it into list form did not work but using the for loop and lambda worked correctly.  Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Something like this?

```
for f in (A, B, C, D):
    if flag == 0:
        f()
```